# How to specify "at most" using predicate logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic

I am supposed to transform the following sentence into predicate logic:
"At most two men can be accepted to each position in Google"
Predicates are already given:

J(x, y) - x is a job position in company y

A(x, y) - x is accepted to job position y

My logic so far is the following:
$∀x∀y∀u∀z (x ≠ u ∧ y ≠ u ∧ x ≠ y) ∧ (J(z, Google)∧  ...))$

Instead of the ... I thought about writing many cases with OR's in between (x and y got accepted to job z and NOT u was accepted to job z OR not x,y, and u were accepted to job z, etc.)

I believe there is a better way to do this than to write literally every case like this to show that at most 2 men can be accepted to each position

Comment: "at most two" is: "there is $x$ and there is $y$ and $x \ne y$ and (for every $z$ either $z=x$ or $z=y$)"

Comment: Hint: "at most n A" = "it is not the case that there exist n+1 distinct elements for which A".